# Swift: Turn on optimization or release mode for a single class

Tags: swift, xcode, optimization

I have a class that takes 3 seconds to process data in Debug mode, but only takes 100ms in Release mode. There is obviously something wrong with it but all tests pass so I don't need any Debug features when using it.

Is there a way to make Xcode run the project in Debug mode but do all Release optimization for this single class?

The only workaround I can think of is to turn this into a framework with a release compile flag but that seems like a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

> The only workaround I can think of is to turn this into a framework with a release compile flag but that seems like a bit overkill.

This is the only stable way to do this at the moment (with Xcode 13). One more option is that you can try doing some timing measurements, it might be possible to rearrange your code so that even the debug codegen gives better results.

If this is throwaway code, you can try marking individual functions with the underscored attribute [`@_optimize(speed)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_optimizenonesizespeed).

I'll repeat the disclaimer at the top of the doc:

> WARNING: This information is provided primarily for compiler and standard library developers. Usage of these attributes outside of the Swift monorepo is STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.

Comment: Thank you for responding - you mention Xcode 12; any difference with Xcode 13? I was unable see results unfortunately so I may go with the framework way. Just because I can't find any more documentation or example uses on this flag, would `@_optimize(speed) func ...` be the correct usage? Or do I need to do something else, like another flag or a line break etc?

Comment: It should work with Xcode 13 too. That said, I'm not 100% sure if this works for methods, I've only seen it used for functions.